# Should questions that request a list of words be CW?

Tags: discussion

If we accept questions that ask for a list of words (where each word can be combined to make a different list), should those questions be a community wiki?

For example, if I ask

> What are the words ending in *-ous* you use most frequently?

Somebody could reply with *dangerous, ferrous*; somebody else with *poisonous, sulfurous*, or with *dangerous, poisonous*, etc. All possible word combinations would be equally correct, or acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. There is a similar rule on SO that questions asking for lists be marked CW, and I think that the same rule should apply here.

Comment: -1; the rule on SO is that these questions should be closed, not marked as CW.

Comment: The comparison with SO is quite not correct; on SO, nobody asks for a list of words.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No, but there [*are*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372/what-is-your-single-most-favorite-command-line-trick-using-bash) list questions.

Answer (score 5):

You open with "If we accept questions..." so I'll stop you right there: we probably shouldn't be.  How could I possibly find it useful to know what "-ous" words are used by random people on the Internet?  Having these sorts of questions around makes it harder to find the real questions, wastes users' time and won't attract experts to the site.

Lists and polls on SE sites should be closed 99% of the time.  Sources:

- [Should we have a “List of X” close reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason/57248#57248)
- [New “Hidden Features” questions: Coincidence, Copycat or Sock Puppet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52456/new-hidden-features-questions-coincidence-copycat-or-sock-puppet/52459#52459)
- [The fourth place: Polling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling)
- [What should the `subjective` tag be used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22182/what-should-the-subjective-tag-be-used-for/22183#22183)
- [“Best of” style questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62010/best-of-style-questions/62012#62012)
- many, many more available upon request or with a quick search

I can't think of a single example of a valuable list question on this site, but I understand that that doesn't mean there isn't one out there.  If an acceptable one comes up, it should have the format of one question and one answer, both marked CW.

Answer (score 4):

**Important change:** as of October 14th, 2010, the ability to mark questions as CW right from the start has been removed across the entire SE network. Visit the meta Meta for further details:

- [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192)
- [Should the community wiki police be shut down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183)